# Connecting MySQL with Visual Studio C#

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I'm new to MySQL Workbench and I'm trying to make a Timekeeping system. I'm wondering how to connect MySQL with Visual Studio C#?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419997/connecting-mysql-with-visual-studio-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you'll need a "connector/driver" to connect from .net to mysql, you can find the official .net connector from mysql here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

the connector will install the MySql.Data library that you has classes to communicate to MySql (MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, MySqlDataAdapter, etc)

Comment: Once you have installed the .net connector, used the mysql.data library, and compiled the .exe, if you execute that .exe on a machine that has not installed the mysql .net connector, will it work?

Comment: A word of warning though, this connector is licensed with GPL, effectively forcing your project to be licensed with it as well and if it's a commercial project developed for another company, they might not be too happy to have it on GPL.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with MySQL for the first time in your PC, do these things.

1. Install MySQL Server ([Link here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)) - 28 MB
2. Install MySQL ODBC Connector [(Link here)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) - 3 MB

Now install SqlYog Community Edition. ( [Link here](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) ). You can manipulate your MySQL Databases using this.

Now in AppSettings of web.config, set two entries like this.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;"/>
    <add key="DataBaseDetails" value="Database=mydatabase;uid=root;pwd=;Option=3;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And call it like in your MySQL class like this.

```
public string MyConnectionString 
{
    get
    {
        //return {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;uid=root;pwd=;Option=3;
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ODBCDriver"]
            + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseDetails"];
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize your connection like this.

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(MyConnectionString);
```

Namespace imported

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use NuGet to get the .Net connector for MySQL:

[image]

Once you install the MySql.Data package, you can do something like this:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabaseName;Uid=root;Pwd=;"))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "select id, name from widgets";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0) + ": " + reader.GetString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this website:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p34

Set up your connection string and then the rest should just work as if you were calling a SQLServer database.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to MySQL using dotConnect for MySQL.

[more information](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/)