# Connection String Problem

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, configuration, connection-string

I'm new to Visual Studio and MySQL. I'm creating a Login Page and connect it with MySQL. But whenever I add a connection string. I always got an error.

[image]

Can anybody tell me what's the problem in here?

Please.

This is my **config file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please share the config file with the connection string?

Comment: looks like you have not tried what was suggested previously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419997/connecting-mysql-with-visual-studio-c/6420213#6420213 please place the key value pairs inside `<appSettings>`

Comment: I edited my config, still have errors..

Comment: That doesn't look like your entire config file.  Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: @Chris: That is all what I have in my config file. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with MySQL connections, but your config file should look more like this

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a syntax error in your `App.config` file.

Check the `InnerException` for details.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means there is a problem with your web.config file.  Probably a tag out of place, not closed, or otherwise jacked.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/01/06/fixing-quot-configuration-system-failed-to-initalize-quot-exception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But whenever I add a connection
>   string. I always got an error.

Your web.config or app.config configuration is not legal in its current form - this could be because of a typo, i.e an unclosed tag, otherwise malformed XML or a section that is unknown or nested in a section where it doesn't belong.