# How to Connect C# to SQLYOG?

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, connection-string, sqlyog

Can someone teach me how to connect C#(VS2010) to SQLYOG? I don't know how to connect my program to my database. I am planning to right a log in program and I don't know the connection string of C#(VS2010) to SQLYOG(Version 3.51). I really need your help guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

[Connecting MySQL with Visual Studio C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419997/connecting-mysql-with-visual-studio-c-sharp)

SQLYOG is just a management application.

- Install a version of the MySQL connector.
- Install an instance of MySQL if you need to.
- Configure your database connection string to said local instance (or remote server).

There's plenty of examples on Stack Overflow and other websites (see above link).

EDIT: There's some nice tutorials on the MySQL dev site actually! - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html