# I have created a MySQL database in MySQL Workbench but am unable to use in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

Hi I am new in C# programming and MySQL but I want to learn it. I have created a database in a MySQL workbench, in which I have created a table and inserted some data.

Now I want to use this database in my C# desktop application. But how do I connect C# with that database? I do not know where the database is located.

If I know the location then I can enter its address in connection string in C#, so my questions are

1. After creating a database in MySQL workbench then where is the file saved?
2. Should I place that database file with my `.exe` file ?

Comment: The file will be stored in you server folder.

Comment: Have a look at this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html - the section on Installation gives details of downloading the required DLLs. The MySqlHelper class takes a lot of the hard work out of reading/updating databases if you are not too sure what you are doing. Understand that you are connecting to the MySQL server engine - that handles connection to the actual database file(s) so they do not need including with your EXE

Comment: You can find better answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419997/connecting-mysql-with-visual-studio-c-sharp link.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Install MySql connector for .net/ODBC
> 2. Install MySql for visual studio
> 3. Import MySql.Web, MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 dlls into your project first.
> 4. Now create a Entity framework data model from your database by right clicking any folder -> new item -> Data -> ADO.net entity data
>      model
> 5. Click Generate from database -> Next
> 6. Click on New Connection -> Change ->
> 7. Select MySql Database as datasource
> 8. Give your MySql server credentials and select database to generate the data model from database
> 9. Now you can create the instance of the entities class and access data from tables like dbEntitiesInstance.TableName.(Make use of LINQ
>      queries too).